# Averaging an average in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table

car

```
 id |  person_id  |  mpg
------------------------  
 4  |     1       |  50
 5  |     1       |  15
 6  |     2       |  10
 7  |     2       |  28
 8  |     3       |  33
```

I need to get an average of each person's mpg and then an average for the group.

```
person 1 avg = (50 + 15) / 2 = 32.5
person 2 avg = (10 + 28) / 2 = 19
person 3 avg = 33

group average = 32.5 + 19 + 33 / 3 = 28.1
```

Is there a query that will do what I need?

Comment: Don't average the averages, as you will loose the weight of the averages.
i.e: 10 cars at 50 mpg average and one car at 10 mpg "average" will give you 30mpg as the total average, which is very wrong :)

Comment: I don't agree.

2 green cars at 50 mpg, 2 red cars at 20 mpg and 1 black car at 10 mpg have two different results:

- averaging everything: 150/5 = 30 mpg
- averaging the averages for each car: (50 + 20 + 10)/3 = 26.667

The first option is as you stated, but not necessarily what is looked for!

Comment: I am comparing one person's average mpg to other people's average mpg with a group average of mpg per person. I don't want the guy with the 10 - 50 mpg cars to skew the results. I want his average of 50 to be averaged with the guy who has 1 car at 10mpg.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT person_id, AVG(mpg) from car group by person_id;
```

If you want to get an average for the group, you should probably do this:

```
SELECT AVG(mpg) from car;
```

Unless you really want to average the averages, which seems a bit dubious to me:

```
SELECT AVG(average) from (SELECT person_id, AVG(mpg) as average from car group by person_id);
```

Answer (score 2):

you cannot solve this in 1 query, but you have to use 2 queries or 1 query en solve the overal average in your code

```
select person, avg(mpg) from cat group by person
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT person_id, AVG(mpg) AS mpg_avg FROM car GROUP BY person_id WITH ROLLUP
```

The `WITH ROLLUP`-modifier will add a line to the result set where `persion_id` is `NULL` and `mpg_avg` is the average over the whole result set (MySQL >= 4.1.1):

```
 person_id | mpg 
------------------
         1 | 32.5 
         2 | 19.0
         3 | 33.0
      NULL | 27.2
```